# Find the DFA for the language L given

Tags: automata, dfa, nfa

L is a language over {`x,y,z`} where `x`'s are never preceded by `y`'s and never followed by `z`'s

Comment: http://meta.softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems

Comment: I post this question because I have have a answer for my own, but I just want to know how other community members solves it.

Comment: What's your answer?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[image: DFA for language L]
This DFA can also be drawn using AND for two part,i.e first part is `x`'s are never preceded by `y`'s
second part is `x`'s are never followed by `z`'s

Comment: This answer should label all non-A states as accepting, and it has an extraneous state that has no transitions into it.